# printing using argv and argc

Tags: c, switch-statement, argv, argc

here is a program which printing some information about my self
in this program if the user scanning /n its printing the name and 
etc. but when i'm running this program using gcc its printing nothing at all.
i need to scan the parameters using argv and argc.
how can i solve that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 10

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (argv[i] == ' ')
        {
            break;
        }
        if (argv[i] == 'n' || argv[i] == 'b' || argv[i] == 'f' || argv[i] == '?' && argv[i - 1] == '/')
        {
            switch (i)
            {

            case 'n':
                printf("my name is : Daniel Zingerman \n");
                break;
            case 'b':
                printf("my birth date is: 2/11 \n");
                break;
            case 'f':
                printf("my favorite food is: ice cream \n");
                break;
            case '?':
                printf("the instruction of the program:");
                printf("There is a lot of parameters you can scan into the program:");
                printf("1. /n - printing the name");
                printf("2. /b - printing the birth date");
                printf("3. /n - printing the favorite food");
                printf("4. /? - printing the instructions");

                break;
            }
        }


    }
    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What's the first surprise that you met with this program?

Comment: compare strings using strcmp from string.h. And argc should limit your for loop, not SIZE.

Comment: what exactly is `case '/n':`?

Comment: There are more severe problems than that, the program will not compile.

Comment: What happens when there are less then 10 command line arguments?

Comment: Is this really a **minimal** example? Surely you could have posted just 1 case (such as `'/n'`) that does *not* work.

Comment: i remove the "/" form the cases

Comment: You want to fix the code until no more warnings are issued by the compiler, then re-test.

Answer (score 0):

You should use argc value to know what is last argument. Or you should test `argv[i] == NULL`. You seem not to understand `argv` is `char **`, so `argv[i]` is a `char *`, not a `char`.

Also learn to use [getopt()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt), or getopt_long().

Answer (score 0):

The `argv[]` array is created from the program name in `argv[0]` and then the command line arguments separated by spaces
/n /b /f will be returned in `argv[1], argv[2] & argv[3]`, not as a single 'string' in `argv[1]`

Use `argc` to limit how many elements of `argv[]` you test, so that you do not go out of bounds:
`for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {`

Now you need to check that you have valid command line arguments:
`if ((strcmp(argv[i], "/n") == 0) || ...`

As you need an integer value for the case tests, use the second element of the argv[i]:
`switch (argv[i][1]) {`